# Invalid hook call(redux-saga)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-saga

```
import { firestore as db } from "../../components/firebase/firebase";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const save = async () => {
  const data = useSelector((state: any) => state.canvas.canvas);
  const auth: any = getAuth();
  await db.collection("images").add({
    user: auth.currentUser.displayName,
    data: data,
  });

  return data;
};
```

I have this code. There I need to get image url from redux store and to save it to firestore, but I'm getting an error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." How can I fix it? This code is calling from saga:

```
export function* imgWorker() {
  const Image: { img: string } = {
    img: "",
  };

  try {
    yield save().then((img) => {
      Image.img = img;
    });
    yield put(saveImgSucceed(Image.img));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("imgSaga", error);
    yield put(saveImgFailed());
  }
}

export function* saveImg() {
  yield takeEvery(GET_IMAGE_DATA, imgWorker);
}
```

Comment: It tells you you cannot use hooks outside a function component/custom hook. Your `save` function is basically a custom hook, which is fine. But since it is a custom hook, therefore a hook, you cannot use it in a context like your `imgWorker` generator function, since that is neither a function component, nor a custom hook. You would need to interact with the db in some other way (depends on what you're using in your project).

Comment: @Catalin-IoanNarita yeah I agree with you. I got that I can't use hooks in saga. Сan't think of any other way to get data from the store, so thats why I posted this question

Comment: Well, you basically need to acces your store state without `useSelector`. Isee that `redux-saga` exposes a `select()` function to do exactly just that.
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#selectselector-args

Comment: On a side note, besides using `select()` as advised above, this specific situation of image uploading might utilize the strength of redux-saga's channels. I find Channels to be an efficient, encapsulated way for interacting with 3rd parties like firebase's image upload. You create a channel that listens to the lifecycle stages of the image uploading process and emits events. You're code is cleaner and you reduce the usage of the store infra as a pub/sub mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { firestore as db } from "../../components/firebase/firebase";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { select, call, takeEvery, put } from "redux-saga/effects"

export const save = function* ()  {
  const data = yield select((state: any) => state.canvas.canvas);
  const auth: any = getAuth();
  
  return yield call(() => db.collection("images").add({
    user: auth.currentUser.displayName,
    data: data,
  }));
};

export function* imgWorker() {
  const Image: { img: string } = {
    img: "",
  };

  try {
    Image.img = yield call(save);
    yield put(saveImgSucceed(Image.img));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("imgSaga", error);
    yield put(saveImgFailed());
  }
}

export function* saveImg() {
  yield takeEvery(GET_IMAGE_DATA, imgWorker);
}
```